# IntelliJ: Selecting a line/text from 0:Messages

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got some error in 0:Messages section of IntelliJ Idea and wanted to select a few lines out of the heaps of Information for posting on stack overflow.

Surprised IntelliJ will allow me to only select and copy the whole heap consisting of several lines.

Is there a way to select and copy a few lines of choice?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? Is there anything I can improve?

Comment: Well, there is always an alternate, but appears lot of efforts for copying a text from a so called IDE....... I will rather take a screenshot and then use OCR to extract the text out of that screenshot :)

Comment: Sure, use whatever is more convenient to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually select not all, but any lines in the Messages tool window using Ctrl/Shift and mouse clicks, then copy the selected lines:

[image: copy selected lines]

If you want to copy one line from the Error, click on the [**Export to Text File**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqoXQ.png) button on the left toolbar, it will open the **Export Preview** dialog from where you can copy any words/lines:

[image]

Comment: Well, there is always an alternate.... I can even take a screenshot and then use OCR to extract the text out of that screenshot :)